# Web scraping job postings from Facebook

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, facebook

I built a web scraper to pull a list of jobs on Facebook and other websites but want to break up the code into functions that I can reuse for other websites. This structure is working but I think it can be more efficient with functions. I'm getting stuck on how to structure the functions. It's only pulling two pages for testing.

```
from time import time
from requests import get
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Range of only 2 pages
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
cities = ["Menlo%20Park%2C%20CA",
          "Fremont%2C%20CA",
          "Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA",
          "Mountain%20View%2C%20CA",
          "Northridge%2CCA",
          "Redmond%2C%20WA",
          "San%20Francisco%2C%20CA",
          "Santa%20Clara%2C%20CA",
          "Seattle%2C%20WA",
          "Woodland%20Hills%2C%20CA"]

# Preparing the monitoring of the loop
start_time = time()
requests = 0

with open('facebook_job_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    header = csv.writer(f)
    header.writerow(["Website", "Title", "Location", "Job URL"])

for page in pages:
    for c in cities:
        # Requests the html page
        response = get("https://www.facebook.com/careers/jobs/?page=" + page +
                       "&results_per_page=100&locations[0]=" + c)

        # Pauses the loop between 8 and 15 seconds
        sleep(randint(8, 15))

        # Monitor the frequency of requests
        requests += 1
        elapsed_time = time() - start_time
        print("Request:{}; Frequency: {} request/s".format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait=True)

        # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn("Request: {}; Status code: {}".format(requests, response.status_code))

        # Break the loop if number of requests is greater than expected
        if requests > 2:
            warn("Number of requests was greater than expected.")
            break

        # Parse the content of the request with BeautifulSoup
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        job_containers = page_soup.find_all("a", "_69jm")

        # Select all 100 jobs containers from a single page
        for container in job_containers:
            site = page_soup.find("title").text
            title = container.find("div", "_69jo").text
            location = container.find("div", "_1n-z _6hy- _21-h").text
            link = container.get("href")
            job_link = "https://www.facebook.com" + link

            with open('facebook_job_list.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                rows = csv.writer(f)
                rows.writerow([site, title, location, job_link])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick suggestions:

The `requests` module can urlencode strings for you if you use the `params` keyword:

```
import requests

cities = ["Menlo Park, CA"]
pages = range(1, 3)
url = "https://www.facebook.com/careers/jobs/"

for city in cities:
    for page in pages:
        params = {"page": page, "results_per_page": 100, "locations[0]": city}
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Organize your code using functions. This allows you to give them a readable name (and even add docstrings).

```
def get_job_infos(response):
    """Parse the content of the request to get all job postings"""
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    job_containers = page_soup.find_all("a", "_69jm")

    # Select all 100 jobs containers from a single page
    for container in job_containers:
        site = page_soup.find("title").text
        title = container.find("div", "_69jo").text
        location = container.find("div", "_1n-z _6hy- _21-h").text
        job_link = "https://www.facebook.com" + container.get("href")
        yield site, title, location, job_link
```

This is a generator over which you can iterate. Using the [`lxml` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) is usually faster.

Note that `csv` can write multiple rows at once using [`writer.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows), which takes any iterable of rows:

```
with open('facebook_job_list.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(get_job_infos(response))
```

This way you only have to open the file once per page, instead of a hundred times. Even better would be to make the whole thing a generator, so you can write all rows while opening the file only once:

```
def get_all_jobs(url, cities, pages):
    for city in cities:
        for page in pages:
            params = {"page": page, "results_per_page": 100, "locations[0]": city}
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            # check status code

            yield from get_job_infos(response)

            # rate throttling, etc here
            ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cities = ["Menlo Park, CA", ...]
    pages = range(1, 3)
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/careers/jobs/"

    with open('facebook_job_list.csv', "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Website", "Title", "Location", "Job URL"])
        writer.writerows(get_all_jobs(url, pages, cities))
```

This way the `get_all_jobs` generator will `yield` jobs as it is being iterated over, getting the next page when needed.